# menu for mobiles no longer working

Tags: jquery, css, html, mobile

When I view  this page for mobiles, the navigation menu no longer  works.I don't know why because it was working before I put the image slider in .

**here is the html markup:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Business Frontpage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/business-frontpage.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/flexslider.css" type="text/css">


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>


    <header>
    <div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="img/slide1.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/slide2.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/slide3.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">.</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
    </header>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h2>What We Do</h2>
                <p>Introduce the visitor to the business using clear, informative text. Use well-targeted keywords within your sentences to make sure search engines can find the business.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et molestiae similique eligendi reiciendis sunt distinctio odit? Quia, neque, ipsa, adipisci quisquam ullam deserunt accusantium illo iste exercitationem nemo voluptates asperiores.</p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#">Call to Action &raquo;</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <address>
                    <strong>Start Bootstrap</strong>
                    <br>3481 Melrose Place
                    <br>Beverly Hills, CA 90210
                    <br>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr>(123) 456-7890
                    <br>
                    <abbr title="Email">E:</abbr> <a href="mailto:#">name@example.com</a>
                </address>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="img/heading1.png" alt="">
                <h2>Marketing Box #1</h2>
                <p>These marketing boxes are a great place to put some information. These can contain summaries of what the company does, promotional information, or anything else that is relevant to the company. These will usually be below-the-fold.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
                <h2>Marketing Box #2</h2>
                <p>The images are set to be circular and responsive. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
                <h2>Marketing Box #3</h2>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

if anyone can provide any  help/solutions to get the menu working on mobiles again this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be a z-index problem. Try modify the z-index of flexslider and navbar class with google inspector and check if the navbar is behind flexslider.

I can't give you a complete solution because I need some code (css, jsfiddle...).

Hope this helps.
Regards